# Query for duplicate meta_value under different meta_key for the same user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying for hours to get all the IDs where 2 different meta_key's meta_value are the same.

E.g. I would expect the below example to return user_id 1 and 2 as their first_name and last_name's meta_value are exactly the same under the same user_id.

| **user_id** | **meta_key** | **meta_value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | first_name | Joe |
| 0 | last_name | Doe |
| 1 | first_name | Peter |
| 1 | last_name | Peter |
| 2 | first_name | Simon |
| 2 | last_name | Simon |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you could just use aggregation:

```
select vals, group_concat(user_id) as user_ids
from (select user_id,
             group_concat(meta_value order by meta_key) as vals
      from t
      where meta_key in ('first_name', 'last_name')
      group by user_id
      having count(*) = 2  -- both keys present
     )
group by vals
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This returns the concatenated keys with a list of user ids that have those values.

Note:  This particular formulation assumes that the names have no commas in them (the default separator for `group_concat()`).  You can adjust the separate to a less commonly used character, such as `|`, if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can self join the table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`user_id` int, `meta_key` varchar(10), `meta_value` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
> VALUES
>     (0, 'first_name', 'Joe'),
>     (0, 'last_name', 'Doe'),
>     (1, 'first_name', 'Peter'),
>     (1, 'last_name', 'Peter'),
>     (2, 'first_name', 'Simon'),
>     (2, 'last_name', 'Simon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id FROM tab1 a INNER JOIN tab1 b 
> ON a.`meta_value` = b.`meta_value` AND a.`meta_key` <> b.`meta_key` 
> AND a.`meta_key` = 'first_name' AND b.`meta_key` = 'last_name'
> ```
>
> ```
> | user_id |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> |       2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80f8fb80f93e14fccd81e9ca5d104574)*